# Макет header'a

Tags: html, css

Скажите пожалуста:

```
<div id="row" style="width:100%;">
  <div id="content" style="margin:0 auto; width: 980px;">
    <div id="left" style="float:left; width: 30%;"></div>
    <div id="right" style="width: 65%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

У меня есть приблизительно такой код. Тоесть блок "Строка", в ньом блок content по центру фиксированый, и в ньом ещё две колонки.

Какие стили ещё нужно добавить, всё правельно отображалось или это уже всё ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы на правильном пути, но не хватает пару элементов. Переписал Ваш пример в один из нескольких вариантов реализации подобной задачи:

**html:**

```
<div class="row" >
    <div class="content">
         <div class="left"></div>
         <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.row{ width: 100%;}  
    .content{ margin:0 auto; width: 980px;}
    .content:after{ content: "."; display: block;clear: both;
    visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0;}
       .left{ float:left; width: 30%;}
       .right{ float:right; width: 65%;}
```